# Mount-SPContentDatabase rollback after upgrade

Tags: 2013, powershell, content-database

We need to move/use a content database from old to new web application.
Scenario goes like:

1. Detach content database from Old Web Application with Windows Classic Authentication mode
2. Attach content database to New Web Application with Claims Based Authentication mode

**Question:** Is it possible to roll it back through Attach Content Database (in Central Admin) or Mount-SPContentDatabase (PowerShell) or is it like a one-way ticket?

I had to ask this here because the DEV & PROD Web Application setup is not alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only when you (re)run `Convert-SPWebApplication` will this be permanent -- unless it came from another farm with either a different version of SharePoint or lower patch level on the same version of SharePoint.

Make a SQL backup first!

Comment: Hi Trevor, it will come from the same farm. No plans on running the `Convert-SPWebApplication`. In fact, the planned script would be `Mount-SPContentDatabase "myDatabase" -DatabaseServer "myServer" -webapplication http://sitename **-NoB2bSiteUpgrade**` and yes we'll do SQL backup too. Given this, I believe we won't be having any problem doing a rollback, yes?

Comment: B2B switch won't do anything, in this case. Same farm. You may need to run an `SPContentDatabase.RefreshSitesInConfigurationDatabase()` post-mount due to moving the database within the same farm to a different Web App. These sites will be inaccessible (for most users) until you run the claims conversion process. I don't see an issue with this, just make sure if the sites don't show up that you run the refresh method above.

Comment: Thanks for the details Trevor. Will give an update tomorrow and hopefully it's a favourable result. Fingers crossed. :)

Comment: Hi Trevor, the content database has been attached successfully through Central Admin "Add content database" option to the new Web Application. However, I noticed that some of the permissions were lost and some were retained. Hope you can provide your insights regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: This is why you would need to run `Convert-SPWebApplication` where the database was mounted since you're going from classic to claims. Once you ran this, you could no longer remount the database to the classic web app.

Comment: We decided to manually re-do the permissions instead of running the PowerShell script. We believe that its about time to audit and arrange the permissions as they were MESSY! Thank you for all your help. I've come across many issues in the past and most of your answers helped me a lot! so.... Thank you very much! :)